# How can I better structure my React components so I may access certain data?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a forum and I have two components. `Board.js` and `Message.js`.

Board is the main page which displays a list of all topics created for the board. I have a `useState` named `topic` which is just an empty array. The `addTopic` function is attached to a form and allows the user to create a topic. `addTopic` simply saves the values and adds a new object to the `topic` array which is then mapped to the page.

Message is for when a user clicks a topic and wants to read the message.

Board has all the code for creating the array and making topics and it also returns jsx. The jsx is a bunch of divs and a table to make the page look user friendly. Message just returns jsx which again is just divs to make the page nice.

**Here's my problem**

When I go to Board.js, Board.js is shown being stacked on top of Message.js, rather than them both being separate pages. I know my file structure is to blame because there's no other way for me to pass props as I just have two components however after making a copy of my entire project and trying to better organize things I am having a really tough time making it work. I'm still new to React so file structure is something I need improvement on and I've been watching videos on YouTube but they only show the basics.

**Board.js**

```
const [topic, setTopic] = useState(() => {
    const topicJson = localStorage.getItem("topic");
    return topicJson ? JSON.parse(topicJson) : [];
  });

const [title, setTitle] = useState();
const [message, setMessage] = useState();

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const handleTitle = (e) => setTitle(e.target.value);
const handleMessage = (e) => setMessage(e.target.value);

const addTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const updatedTopic = [
      ...topic,
      {
        title: title,
        message: message,
      },
    ];

    setTopic(updatedTopic);
  };

return (
// CSS has been removed for readability but it's just a bunch of divs and tables

{topic
  .filter((x) => x.board === id)
  .map(
     (
      { // object values }, index
     ) => (
      // table jsx code
     ))}

{show ? (
  <form onSubmit={addTopic}>
    Write your topic
    <label htmlFor="title">
       <input
         id="title"
         name="title"
         value={title}
         onChange={handleTitle}
      ></input>
   </label>
   Write your message
   <label htmlFor="message">
     <textarea
       id="message"
       name="message"
       value={message}
       onChange={handleMessage}
   ></textarea>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">
   Post Message
  </button>
</form>
) : null}

<MessageDetail topic={topic} />
```

**Message.js**

```
const Message = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <span>{props.message}</span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Soo. what are you trying? code splitting?

Comment: @Normal Hello. I think what I really need help with is better understanding the structure behind React. I need access to the `topic` array for both components but passing it onto `Message.js` is stacking my components which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you make a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for it?

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components